# R export to sas but cannot open

Tags: r, sas, export

I export data from R to sas format with package `haven`. However, when I open my `.sas7bdat` data. It fails.

```
library(haven)
write_sas(M, "C:/Users/user/desktop/MERGED_data.sas7bdat")
```

I provide my data structure below:
[image: str(M)]

Here is the properties.
[image: properties]

I double click the data to open in sas, but it fails and provides the information.
[image: error]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you try passing `as.data.frame(M)`

Comment: this is  `data.table` and `data.frame` classes.

Comment: Unlike the excellent `read_sas` counterpart, `write_sas` is still a bit limited in my experience. I haven't got it to work with anything beyond a very basic example yet - there is an open Github issue trying to route around this, but the `sas7bdat` format seems difficult to parse. https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/224

Comment: `write_sas` is not very reliable yet. The most reliable way I found to get datasets from R to SAS is writing them to an sqlite file and reading them via DBI in SAS. 

The package `foreign` also privoides good R to SAS export but is very slow. (Files are converted to CSV and a SAS-script to read the CSV is produced.)

Comment: Are you using Unix or Windows version of SAS?  SAS datasets cannot use uppercase letters in the membername on unix, but I would expect a different error if that was the issue.

Comment: @Tom Windows. It's weird.

Comment: Did you try generating a SAS XPORT format file instead? That should work better since the format is published.  You might need to limit your variable names to 8 characters and string values to max 200 characters.